# Why do I need to log in to Github

Tags: go, github

Because xlsx tag v1.1.0 does `not contain the latest features`, I use the following command to update the xlsx package to **master**

```
# go get github.com/bingoohuang/xlsx@master
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

Why do I still need to **login** to download the github public code, this does not happen when I download packages from other `go get`

The strange thing is that I can execute it `on windows`, but the above login question occurs `on centos7`.

what caused this to happen? I really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: maybe you can check your ~/.gitconfig have sth like "url xxx instead of"?

Comment: There might be something in your git config. Check `git config --list`.

Comment: @ashing  Viewed through cat, there are no related fields
`
cat ~/.gitconfig
[push]
        default = simple
[http]
        postBuffer = 1048576000
[core]
        longpaths = true
        quotepath = off
[filter "lfs"]
        clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
        smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
        process = git-lfs filter-process
        required = true
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `github.com/bingoohuang/xlsx@master` depends on [`github.com/bingoohuang/go-yaml`](https://github.com/bingoohuang/go-yaml), which either does not exist or is private.

Because GitHub responds with a 404 error for private repositories, it is likely this missing repository is causing `go get` to issue a password prompt.

A `go get` for a library without missing dependencies (e.g., `go get github.com/rs/zerolog@master`) works without a problem.